# Binance Baker (not on the Exchange)

Tags: baker, rewards

I delegated my XTZ to Binance Baker (not on the Binance Exchange but Binance Baker as an independent baker - delegation address:  tz1S8MNvuFEUsWgjHvi3AxibRBf388NhT1q2) on March 14th (from Cycle 218).

I checked TezStat to make sure that my delegation has been included properly etc.  According to the baker information, Binance Baker's pay-out cycle is 10 cycles, which, as I understood it, means that once Cycle 228 gets unfrozen, I would receive my first pay-out including the total of last 10 cycle rewards (from Cycles 218 to 228).  After waiting for about 2 months, Cycle 228 was unfrozen (about 5 days ago- on May 18th-ish) and now up to Cycle 229 being unfrozen.  On TezStat, I can see on the said baker's page  my delegation baking about 2.5 XTZs every cycle.

Yet, I have not received any pay-outs yet. I would very much appreciate if anyone could shed light on this situation.  I am writing this on May 23rd.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, exchanges do not payout if you delegate to them. They don't act like normal bakers that takes delegations. Their advertised fees and payouts are for if and only if you keep your funds inside their exchange. They don't even advertise the address they use to bake, community members figured it out using some detective work.

In short, by delegating to them, they have no obligations to pay you any of the rewards they earned from your stake. I would move your delegation elsewhere to a reliable baker.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have asked this question earlier.  It seems that I have wasted about 2 months (+1 month with a new baker).  My TezosBaker should mention this point clearly.  I need to contact them.